# HTTP/1.1 New Session Failed

Tags: iis, configuration, session, asp

I'm getting reports from my users that they are getting the following error message when going to my website:

> HTTP/1.1 New Session Failed

It doesn't happen all the time. (I checked my site today randomly about 20 times and I only saw it once.)

My site is built with ASP.  It is actually simple HTML, but I use ASP because I have my HTML broken up into 5-6 files and am using #include (the only ASP command I'm using) to dynamically combine these files.  I'm doing this because several areas of my pages are static (such as a "News" section that is the same on every page of my site, and I keep it in a separate file to easily update it once for the entire site).

My site is hosted in a Windows IIS environment.  As I'm using a hosting company, I don't have access to IIS, I configure everything through web.config.

I added the following to web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

...thinking that this would prevent the use of sessions.  Like I said before, my site is all simple HTML and therefore sessions aren't necessary. HOWEVER, this didn't help and I did see the error after adding this bit.

I'm assuming that I'm getting the error because of memory issues. If I'm only using ASP's #include command, **how can I simplify my site so that I no longer get the error?  Is there some web.config section I should be including so that IIS manages memory better?**

*EDIT: I just asked the server company about adding memory to my instance and they explained that because I'm on a shared server, that's not possible. They did offer me a more expensive plan, but that just seems ridiculous for my simple site that hardly gets any traffic.*

My web.config is quite long, so if you need to see a specific part of it to help debug the problem, just let me know and I'll post it.

Now, the techs at the hosting company I'm using are useless.  They're suggesting stuff like, "I don't see an error when bringing up your site. Try using Firefox browser instead of Chrome... see if that helps." Ugh. I'm not sure how changing an end user's browser would fix a server issue... Anyway...

If I can't resolve this issue, I'm thinking of doing the following:

- Switch all of my pages to PHP instead of ASP to see if PHP works better. I originally chose ASP because I figured it is ancient technology that would be stable at this point.
- Last resort: Switch all of my pages to HTML and use an offline program to generate them when one of the static areas changes. (The news section typically gets updated about once per month so this wouldn't be such a bad solution really--but, seriously, isn't this sort of thing what ASP is for?!)

EDITEDIT: I've switched over the main page on my site to PHP and will keep an eye on the site over the next few days to see if I get any more errors. Let's see if PHP is more stable than ASP. NOTE: I did run up against [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538203/how-to-avoid-echoing-character-65279-in-php) when converting my main page to PHP, so I converted my included files to plain UTF-8 encoding (without BOM, whatever that is...) and it seems to be working.

EDITEDITEDIT: I checked my site two dozen times throughout the day and didn't see the error even once.  I'm going to continue monitoring this for a couple of days, and if all goes well I'll convert the rest of my site from ASP to PHP.

Comment: I recommend trying PHP, it's far more powerful, faster, stable, secure techology than ASP.

Comment: @suspectus, thanks for the comment. The translation of the pages would be trivial, so I'm going to give this a few more days to see if anyone can come up with an ASP solution before doing the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a solution to the ASP problem. So, I converted all of my pages from ASP to PHP and I haven't seen any errors at all. I'm not thrilled, but the problem is solved.

I hope you find this useful.